# IE display partial cells

Tags: internet-explorer, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid with no problems in Chrome and Firefox, however when attempting to display this in IE, I only see partial cells.  I have been looking for tags that may not be closed or css that may be causing the issue, but I have not been able to track it down yet.  Has anyone else seen this before?

IE Example: [IE Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWYqb.jpg)

As opposed to Chrome and FireFox: [Chrome Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfqqp.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net or link to a live site? We can't debug images ;)

Answer (score 0):

Time for me to feel like an idiot.  Adding the doctype to my layout.jsp for my tiles solved the problem.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```